# Why doesn't a case statement in BigQuery behave as expected?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am learning BigQuery and have some knowledge of SQL. My colleague and I have both built a query to count the number of sessions on our site that have seen a particular event where `eventInfo.eventCategory = "view"` and `hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "basket"`. I used a case statement and they used a subquery with a join.

The version with the case statement doesn't give the same answer as what is seen in Google Analytics, where as the version using the subquery and left join gives a matching result (*which is the result we are looking for*).

Is there something wrong with the first query or is my understanding of case statements and my implementation wrong?

I chose to use a case statement because we have lots of events that we're using to build a funnel and I thought adding in more case statements would be easier to write, read and maintain than a load of subqueries and joins.

Any help in understanding why these give different results would be greatly appreciated.

(This is my first post so I hope I've included enough/not too much info).

Version using a **case** statement:

```
#standardSQL

select
  count(CONCAT(t1.fullvisitorid, CAST(t1.visitID AS string))) AS sessions
  ,case
    when (lower(hits.eventInfo.eventCategory) = "view"
      and lower(hits.eventInfo.eventAction) = "basket")
      then "Basket"
    end
      as funnel_stage
  ,hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
  ,hits.eventInfo.eventAction
  ,t1.date as _date
FROM
  `table_name` t1
  ,UNNEST(hits) hits
where totals.visits = 1
group by _date
  ,hits.eventInfo.eventCategory
  ,hits.eventInfo.eventAction
having funnel_stage is not null
```

Version using a **subquery** and a **join**:

```
#standardSQL

select
count(distinct(s.session)) as All_Sessions,   
count(distinct(e.session)) as Segment
from
(
  select CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitID AS string)) as session
  from `table_name`
) s
left join
(
select CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitID AS string)) as session
  from `table_name`,
  unnest(hits) h
where
lower(eventInfo.eventCategory) = 'view'
AND lower(eventinfo.eventAction) = 'basket'
) e

on s.session = e.session
```

Comment: Those queries count differently, #2 applies DISTINCT, #1 has a `where totals.visits = 1`. And the CASE is quite useless, as it returns only a single value (and then you filter the NULLs in HAVING, why aggregate data you don't want?).

Comment: I added `where total.visits = 1` because I was reading about BigQuery returning different session counts to GA due to sessions with no interaction and thinking this may be the cause (but adding it didn't change the result of #1). I don't understand why the CASE only returns a single value, I thought it returned a value for each row in the data and then I aggregate (count)

Comment: The CASE returns either `Basket` or `NULL`, but you group by all `eventCategory/eventAction` combinations first and then remove all but 'view/basket'

Comment: There are lots of different `eventCategory/eventAction` combinations but I only want to return the ones I'm interested in. There will be multiple `CASE` statements in the final query, one for each event that I want so filtering on `NULL` seemed to make sense without putting in a filter that matches each `CASE`. Is there a way to get the results of #2 in the format of #1 (with `CASE`)?

Comment: It's probably possible, but I don't now about your data model. Filtering *after* (=HAVING) aggregation is always less efficient than *before* (=WHERE), unless only a small precentage of rows is filtered.

Comment: @robot_penguin Looking at the above, I think a good next step would be to make your CASE do some of the summing. Right now you are categorizing with case, but you can also perform aggregations with the categorized data by counting rows where events meet a certain criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approaches to find the specific event is to `cross join` the table with its sub-table/array `hits`. But since you want to count sessions without having any dimension/group on this hit-level, you shouldn't expand the table to hit-scope.

Instead use sub-queries to access these sub-tables/arrays - you can use them in `SELECT` to create kind of a segment or in `WHERE` to filter directly.

Segment approach (using GA sample dataset - so it's a different event):

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  (SELECT
    coalesce( LOGICAL_OR(eventinfo.eventcategory = 'Enhanced Ecommerce'
      AND eventinfo.eventaction = 'Add to Cart'),false) FROM t.hits) hasAdd2CartEvent,
   SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_201707*` t
GROUP BY
  1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Coalesce is just eliminating the NULL-values in case no event was found at all in the session which we want to result in `false`.

The `WHERE` approach uses the same sub-query:

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_201707*` t
WHERE 
  (SELECT
    coalesce( LOGICAL_OR(eventinfo.eventcategory = 'Enhanced Ecommerce'
      AND eventinfo.eventaction = 'Add to Cart'),false) FROM t.hits) 
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY 1
```

Hope this enables you to write more powerful queries :)

Edit:
Just in case you ever need to cross join down to hit-scope and count sessions, you'll have to `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) AS sessions`